# symfony 2 how to send data when redirecting

Tags: symfony

I fetch an object from a database and then I want to make a redirect to the other controller and send there that object:

```
$user = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('ShopMyShopBundle:Register')->find($id);

return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('ShopMyShopBundle_homepage'), array('user' => $user));
```

How Can I get an object after redirecting and send to a template in the other controller function which looks like this:

```
public function indexAction()
{
    return $this->render('ShopMyShopBundle:Main:index.html.twig');
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can't send an object via a redirect. What you can do is send one of its unique properties (probably the primary key) and fetch it from the database again. In your case, it could be a user ID or nickname.

```php
/**
 * @Route("/shop/{nickname}", name="shop_index")
 */
public function indexAction(User $user)
{
    // ...
}
```

Thanks to the type hinting, the user will be fetched from the database [automatically](http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/SensioFrameworkExtraBundle/annotations/converters.html) by its nickname.

Comment: How Can I send the $user variable to a template. I have &user = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('ShopMyShopBundle:Register')->find($id); and then I want to make something like this:  return $this->render('ShopMyShopBundle:Main:register.html.twig', array('form' => $form->createView(), 'user' => $user)); but I get an error "Notice: Undefined variable: user in ...  "

Comment: I found a mistake, maybe you wrong understood me. I forgot to use the EntityManager. Now I have: $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager(); $user = $em->getRepository('ShopMyShopBundle:Register')->find($id); return $this->render('ShopMyShopBundle:Main:register.html.twig', array('form' => $form->createView(), 'user' => $user)); and in the template I can use for example {{user.login}};